# subsetting for distances within a grid space

Tags: r

I have a simple grid area which is represented by a letter/Number combination moving horizontally and a Number moving vertically like so;

```
   E0  E1  E2  E3  E4  E5  E6  E7  E8  E9  F0  F1  F2
52
51
50
49
48
47
46
45
43
42
41
40
39
38
```

and I have a series of data which represent fishing trips, one trip_ID may have multiple rows from different squares within the grid. I would like r to show me all of the trips which contain rows more than 2 grid squares (up/down/diagonally) apart. It is slightly more complicated where the trip may have 3+ rows with different squares, I am only interested in trips where the uninterrupted distance between two grid refs is greater than 2 squares. 
If someone could point me in the right direction of any useful packages, I am aware of geographical distance plotting ones but I thought that as its just a hypothetical grid space there might be an easier way around it.

The data looks like this;

```
Trip_Id   Rectangle_Ns   Rectangle_Ew   Landings(t)      
160120    52             FO             1
240097    45             E4             1
240097    48             E1             1
180057    51             E2             1
180057    50             E1             1
259802    42             E7             1
251087    39             E5             1
251087    42             E6             1
160834    44             E8             1
160834    44             E7             1
129486    44             E6             1
129486    46             E5             1
129486    47             E7             1
```

For example here I'd like it to pick out trips; 240097 and 251087.